# Load OCX component from a different location

Tags: com, ocx

Is it possible to load an OCX component for one application from a different location than the system default without unregistering the one in the System32 directory with regsvr32?  Two applications are having conflicts with an OCX component.

Comment: Welcome to DLL hell. If you have 2 OCX files with the same name, even though they are in different locations, you will still run into COM issues.

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: C++ in VS2005 but we're trying to resolve conflicts for already compiled applications

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Registration-Free Activation will work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Comment: Does this example work in VS2008 and Windows 7?

I got an embedded manifest to work using the IDE but that example for the external manifest doesn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe the apps have embedded manifests already? I'm not sure if an external manifest can add aspects to an existing embedded manifest (such as reg-free activation details)

Comment: Generally registration free COM works OK, but it's a bit fuzzy about the manifest formatting. There are tools out there that help you generate the manifest. As far as I know it's the windows dll-loader itself that has been changed to allow such isolation, and I believe it only works on XP and upwards. It also only works for in-process files such as dll's.

Application virtualization is generally a better way to deal with incompatibilities like this, but obviously requires that you have access to such tools.

Answer (score 0):

If the OCX file are differnt versions then you should be able to register both, but it is unlikely they have been versioned properly (or created properly) so the answer I'm afraid with a COM object is no.